# How to ignore escape sequences stored in PowerShell string variable?

Tags: regex, powershell, escaping

In my PowerShell script, I'm running Select-String over a number of files, looking for a string passed into it via a variable ($id):

```
foreach ($file in (ls "path\to\files")) {
    $found = $false
    $found = Select-String -Path $file $id -Quiet
    if ($found) {
        break
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the $id variable sometimes things like "\C" or "\T", which Select-String tries to interpret as escape sequences.  These are not valid escape sequences, so Select-String throws an error.  They are not intended to be escape sequences (e.g., it could be part of a file path such as "C:\Test"), so how can I prevent PowerShell/Select-String from interpreting them as such?  I've tried using parentheses around $id with no luck.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the static `escape()` method, it instructs the regular expression engine to interpret these characters literally rather than as metacharacters:

```
$id = [regex]::escape($id)
```

You can also turn the command to a one liner (`-path` can take a collection of files):

```
Select-String -Path path\to\files\\* -Pattern ([regex]::escape($id)) -Quiet
```

Comment: I'd give another +1 for the one-liner, if I could up-vote twice. :-)

Comment: Sadly the one-liner doesn't work for the specific situation - I cut out a -Filter and a -Recurse parameter

Comment: In that case:

dir path\to\files -r | Select-String -Pattern ([regex]::escape($id)) -Quiet -list

Comment: `[regex]::escape()` is indeed the method to use to treat strings as literals (verbatim) in the  context of a regular expression in general, but with `Select-String` specifically, the simpler solution is to use the `-SimpleMatch` switch.

Answer (score 1):

Select-String has a `-SimpleMatch` parameter that will cause the cmdlet to do simple string matches instead of regular expressions. If you change the script to do:

```
 $found = Select-String -Path $file $id -Quiet -SimpleMatch
```

it should work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

If the $id string already contains something like TAB when it's passed to you then I'm not aware of a built in method to safely escape it back to "\t".  You need to make sure your script is passed the correct string in the first place.  I.e. it needs to passed 0x5C74 (\t) not 0x09 (TAB). So the escaping needs to be done when the the search string is first defined.

Regex.Escape will escape TAB -> \t but will also escape any of these characters that have meaning within regular expressions:

\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #, and white space

e.g.    . -> \.