# PowerShell: "-windowstyle hidden" breaks otherwise working script

Tags: powershell, download, hidden, execute

I have a relatively simple request: I have a small script that I want to be able to paste into the "run" dialogue of Windows to download and install the Steam installer. It downloads the executable from the official website to the user's %temp% and executes it once the download has finished.

```
PowerShell.exe -command (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/client/installer/SteamSetup.exe','%TEMP%\steam.exe');Start-Process "%TEMP%\steam.exe"
```

However, I would also like to hide the PowerShell window that is spawned. I looked this up and found the -windowstyle argument, which, when set to "hidden", should do what I want. However, after adding this tag, the download part of the initial function still works, but the installer is no longer executed when the download finishes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible you just hit limitation of Run dialogue command length.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window

??