# Force install Microsoft Edge extension enterprise environment

Tags: google-chrome-extension, configuration, active-directory, microsoft-edge, group-policy

I am trying to automatically install a Microsoft Edge Extension in an enterprise managed environment: Google Chrome allow this behavior (check [this](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist) post for further information), but it seems impossible to do the same for Edge (the Edge extension policy states that ["The installation must be initiated and completed by the user, using only the user experience provided by Microsoft Edge and the Microsoft Store"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/microsoft-browser-extension-policy)).

**Edit 5/8/20**

The new Microsoft Edge based on Chromium supports GPOs (cfr. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#extensioninstallforcelist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to forcefully install an extension in a managed environment using [this guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/teju_shyamsundar/2016/05/30/deploy-an-application-from-windows-store-for-business-via-system-center-configuration-manager/).
Unfortunately, when the user open Edge for the first time after the extension has been configured a popup shows up, asking him if he wants to turn the extension on or not, and right now there is no way to forcefully enable the extension.

Comment: Not yet, but I'm waiting for the new Microsoft Edge release... Since it would be based on Chromium it may support GPO

Answer (score 1):

As you've said, I think it's not yet possible. You may check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640148/how-can-i-install-a-microsoft-edge-extension-without-user-interaction) which also stated that *installation of extensions for Microsoft Edge must be initiated and completed by the user.* However, there's a suggestion to try [Add-AppxPackage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856048.aspx) which adds a signed app package (.appx) to a user account. Just make sure that package is signed because otherwise Add-AppxPackage would not work.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately the extension is still considered untrusted, and needs to be manually reenabled each time the user restarts Edge (not the best user experience ever IMHO :) ).