# Avoid window pop-up when using ScheduledTask

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I dont want the blue window to pop up when my script gets run.
It should be done in the background as it is for a screen at a public place :)

I tried with `-Argument '-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden`

My full code is:

```
function Create-Schedule{
    $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument '-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -command "& {C:\PowerPointScript\myscript.ps1}"'
    $trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (get-date) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1)
    Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "Powerpoint" -Description "Run Powerpoint download script every 5th min"
}
```

Comment: You can use `-File` to launch a script. `-Argument '-NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -File "C:\PowerPointScript\myscript.ps1"'`

Comment: You could simple hide the console see more at - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40621143/6059896.  Which would be a powershell only solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a PowerShell script without displaying a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution to this problem seems to be to schedule this .VBS in the task scheduler.

```
 command = "powershell.exe -nologo -command C:\Scripts\YourScript.ps1"
 set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 shell.Run command,0
```

Comment: I´ll give it a try!

Comment: Hmm dosn't seem to work. I edited the schedule added from my original script and pointet the file path to the .vbs script instead of the ps1 file...

Comment: I've canged the path in your example to the right path like `C:\PowerPointScript\myscript.ps1`

Comment: Sometimes schedules have really strange behavior, especially when editing and importing and exporting etc. Try to create a new fresh schedule and select the correct operating system and account etc. Also you could try to just double-click the .VBS to test if it is due to the script or due to the schedule. The script I provided should definitely work, I've tested on Windows 10 and Server 2012.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks for letting us know :)