# How to hide console but not GUI in a self elevating Powershell script

Tags: winforms, powershell

I want to make a GUI for my Powershell  scripts so others can easily use them too.
I have a main-menu script witch calls some other scripts. 
For one of them I needed an elevated Powershell process.

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSFilePath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }
```

Now my problem is, that not only the GUI from $PSFilePath is shown but also an empty console window in the background

I tried to use -WindowStyle Hidden

```
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSFilePath`"" -WindowStyle Hidden -Verb RunAs; exit }
```

But that resulted in both the console and the GUI being hidden.

Anyway to hide that console window but not the GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try...](http://blog.dbsnet.fr/hide-powershell-console-from-a-gui)

```
# Hide PowerShell Console
Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);
'
$consolePtr = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow()
[Console.Window]::ShowWindow($consolePtr, 0)
```

But your post is a potential duplicate of this..

[Opening PowerShell Script and hide Command Prompt, but not the GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617800/opening-powershell-script-and-hide-command-prompt-but-not-the-gui)

Comment: Works! (0=hidden, ShowMinimized=2, etc: cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/40621143/1486850

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution some time ago, It's buried somewhere here, on StackOverflow, but can't find a link to it right now. It will open and immediately close empty console window.

Just paste it at the beginning of your script:

```
$dllvar = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindow(int handle, int state);'
add-type -name win -member $dllvar -namespace native
[native.win]::ShowWindow(([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess() | Get-Process).MainWindowHandle, 0)
```