# How to prevent PowerShell from showing a window (blink of an eye), when launching it as a scheduled task with -WindowStyle Hidden?

Tags: powershell

When launching PowerShell.exe as a scheduled task with the options `-WindowStyle Hidden -NoProfile -Command <cmd>`, the blue PowerShell window opens in the blink of an eye and then dissapears (runs as a background process).

How can I prevent the blue PowerShell window from appearing in a split second, which can lead to confusion for the end-user?

Comment: This has been asked before.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a PowerShell script without displaying a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window)

Comment: None of these answers solve my issue. They all depend on 3-party applications, and the -LogonType S4U` doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

On the **General** tab of the scheduled task, select "**Run whether user is logged on or not**" to ensure the task does not pop up a window.

[image: Run whether user is logged on or not]

To do the same thing in PowerShell, use **-LogonType S4U** for the task principal configuration. Example below:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute notepad.exe
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date).AddMinutes(1)
$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType S4U -RunLevel Highest

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Test1337" -TaskPath "\" -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Principal $principal
```

Tested and confirmed on Windows Server 2016 build 1607 (and many other versions by way of previous deployments using this same method).

Comment: Thank you, but how can I select this option, when registering the scheduled task from PowerShell?

Comment: Answer has been updated with PowerShell example using -LogonType S4U to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Ahh, so in this case the task cannot run under the user account who invokes the PowerShell command? Usually, the task has been registered without supplying credentials for the invoking user account.