# Powershell: Send a toast notification to logged user when running as Local System

Tags: powershell, toast, local-system-account

I have a script running as Local System which does some stuff, including checking if it's a user logged on,  and if yes, it runs a PowerShell snippet to show a toast notification, such as below.

If the PS runs as current user, it works ok. If it runs as LocalSystem, the current user does not see the toast because the output is sent Session 0 (for local system account).

Is it possible to display a toast notification to logged on user, if running as Local System and **without** requesting user's credentials?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
$global:balloon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$path = (Get-Process -id $pid).Path
$balloon.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($path) 
$balloon.BalloonTipIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::Info 
$balloon.BalloonTipText = "$Text"
$balloon.BalloonTipTitle = "$Title" 
$balloon.Visible = $true 
$balloon.ShowBalloonTip($Miliseconds)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Intro

It is possible to display a toast notification to the current active logged on user using PowerShell if running as the SYSTEM user in *Session 0* without requesting the user's credentials.

Two solutions to do this follow the "Background Notes"

#### Background Notes

Please note that this section is written for all viewers of this post, rather than just the original questioner.

`SYSTEM` refers to the synonyms `NT Authority\SYSTEM` and `Local System`.

Many Windows services run as the `SYSTEM` user although others run as users with less privileges such as `LOCAL SERVICE` and `NETWORK SERVICE`.

For each logged in user a Windows session is created numbered from 1 which contains the user's windows.

An additional background session called *Session 0* is also created which the Windows services and User Mode Drivers run in. More info at the following link.

[Sessions, Desktops, and Windows Stations](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations/ba-p/372473#)

All services except the *Per-User Services* run in *Session 0*.

If you are using a service for such a script I recommend looking at using one of the two alternatives below:

1. Create a *Session 1* sub-process as already done by some services.
2. Use the `Windows Task Scheduler` instead to run your main script or notification script in the same session as the current active user. This schedule task can be set to trigger on an event.

Note the following security caveat. Scripts in Powershell 5 can be interrupted giving control to a user. For Powershell 6 and later this behaviour is disabled by use of the noninteractive option.

#### Solution Notes

Two solutions are presented below to solve the original problem. Both use an intervening program to move from *Session 0* to *Session 1*.

Both will flash briefly a PowerShell window which is disconcerting for users and is hard to hide. Some hiding tips are provided in the link below.

[How To Run A PowerShell Script Without Display a Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window)

The following solutions as typed require paths without spaces. Full paths must be used if given. You will have to edit these paths to suit.

Test methodology is included.

The first solution requires the `PSExec.exe` program. It is part of `PSTools` available at the following link. It is also used to test both solutions.

[PSTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools)

The second solution requires the `ServiceUI.exe` program. It is part of the `Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT)` available at the following link.

[Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=54259)

The `ServiceUI.exe` program is buried in the `MDT` install directory as follows.

`Microsoft Deployment Toolkit\Templates\Distribution\Tools\x64\ServiceUI.exe`

I copied it to `E:\Programs\MDT\ServiceUI.exe` to make it simpler to use in PowerShell

#### Scripts needed

BalloonTest.ps1

```
$Miliseconds=50000
$Text="Hi"
$Title="Test"

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
$global:balloon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$path = (Get-Process -id $pid).Path
$balloon.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($path) 
$balloon.BalloonTipIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::Info 
$balloon.BalloonTipText = "$Text"
$balloon.BalloonTipTitle = "$Title" 
$balloon.Visible = $true 
$balloon.ShowBalloonTip($Miliseconds)
```

WhoAmISession.ps1

```
whoami
$Session=(Get-Process -PID $pid).SessionID
echo "Session=$Session"
```

#### Test Setup

Start a `cmd.exe` window as the `Administrator`.

The following command will provide a SYSTEM user *Session 0* PowerShell execution environment as shown in the image.

```
E:\Programs\PSTools\psexec -s powershell.exe -file e:\test\WhoAmISession.ps1
```

[image: PSExec Session]

#### Solution 1: PSExec.exe

To show the Toast notification in `PowerShell` if running as the `SYSTEM` user in `Session 0`  use the following command. This will show the Toast notification if the current active logged in user is using `Session 1`. Some modification will be needed for other sessions.

```
E:\Programs\PSTools\psexec -s -i 1 C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file e:\test\BalloonTest.ps1
```

To test start a `"cmd.exe"` window as the `"Administrator"` and enter the following command. This will show the Toast notification if the current active logged in user is using `Session 1` as shown in the image.

```
E:\Programs\PSTools\psexec -s powershell.exe E:\Programs\PSTools\psexec -s -i 1 C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file e:\test\BalloonTest.ps1
```

[image: PSExec Balloon Test]

#### Solution 2: ServiceUI.exe

To show the Toast notification in `PowerShell` if running as the `SYSTEM` user in `Session 0`  use the following command. This will show the Toast notification to the current active logged in user.

```
E:\Programs\MDK\ServiceUI.exe C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file e:\test\BalloonTest.ps1
```

To test start a `"cmd.exe"` window as the `"Administrator"` and enter the following command. This will show the Toast notification to the current active logged in user as shown in the image.

```
E:\Programs\PSTools\psexec -s powershell.exe E:\Programs\MDK\ServiceUI.exe C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file e:\test\BalloonTest.ps1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the very good [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62231480/3055345):

## Alternative solutions to run as another user

The following scripts can be used as alternatives to `psexec` and `ServiceUI.exe` mentioned in said answer, in a similar fashion, when called from `SYSTEM`:

- [RunAsUser](https://github.com/KelvinTegelaar/RunAsUser/) (calls the Windows Win32 API)
- [Invoke-CommandAs](https://github.com/mkellerman/Invoke-CommandAs) (defers the execution to temporary [PS scheduled jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psscheduledjob/about/about_scheduled_jobs))

Note that I haven't extensively tested these options and there may be restrictions, e.g. wrt executing user (if other than `SYSTEM`) or [execution policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies), depending on what context you use them in.
I nevertheless think they are worth mentioning, as they can be good solutions for certain use cases.

## Using scheduled tasks

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62231480/3055345) mentioned the possibility of using scheduled tasks, but didn't expand on it.

This solution has the following advantages (some shared with other solutions):

- it doesn't require the installation/import of any external tool or script
- it can be run outside of `SYSTEM` (e.g. by a different user with administrative rights)
- it can be automatized (it isn't needed for the user to manually register a dedicated task)
- it can be atomized (only the toast-displaying code can be deferred to a dedicated task, leaving the main script to run separately on its own terms).

The idea is to register a scheduled task that will execute PowerShell, telling it to run a toast-displaying script. The task is registered so as to run as the currently logged-in user, is manually and immediately triggered (by the script-running, not-logged-in user -- e.g. `SYSTEM`), and finally deleted.

This is the basic code to achieve this, supposing the toast display logic is contained in a `toast-showing-script.ps1` file<sup>1</sup> which, as an example, expects one `ToastScriptParam` parameter:

```ps
$LoggedInUser = Get-CimInstance –ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -expand UserName

$TaskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute “powershell.exe” -Argument "-NoLogo -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File .\path\to\toast-showing-script.ps1 -ToastScriptParam ""$ToastContent"""  # clearly, you will want to adapt the arguments to fit your use case
$TaskPrincipal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId $LoggedInUser
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $TaskAction -Principal $TaskPrincipal

$ScheduledTask = $null
try {
    $ScheduledTask = Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'TempToast' -TaskPath '\TempToast' -InputObject $Task
    Start-ScheduledTask -InputObject $ScheduledTask
} finally {
    if ($ScheduledTask) {
        Unregister-ScheduledTask -InputObject $ScheduledTask -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

As a further example, you can refer to (or use) this [`ToastNotification` PS module](https://github.com/desseim/rdiff-backup-wrapper-win/tree/master/Modules/ToastNotification) I have written that does just that, but offers a few more options. It allows any user to simply call `Show-NotificationToLoggedInUser -Title "A title" -Message "Longer message"` to display a toast notification to the user currently logged in. It is part of another unrelated project but the module itself can be used as stand-alone.

---

<sup>1</sup> You could, of course, just as well put this logic in a script block instead. Just keep in mind that in the case of a scheduled task, `powershell.exe` isn't "run from another PowerShell host" so you can't pass it a `ScriptBlock`, only a string. Refer to [Microsoft documentation on the `-Command` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe#-command) for details.

Comment: Above code needs the following corrections to work: 1) Replace typographic quotes around _powershell.exe_ with double quotes. 2) Replace the hyphen before _ClassName_ with a minus.