# How does the Command::new API hide the window of the calling program on Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell

For example, I get the result of `Query User` by calling `powershell.exe`:

```rust
let output = Command::new("powershell.exe")
    .arg("Query")
    .arg("User")
    .output()?;

// Parse the output in std...
```

Unfortunately, doing so will bring up a powershell window (although it will soon disappear).

Is there a way to call the console program without displaying any windows?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Rust, `Command` is just doing what you tell it to do, namely run powershell. To run powershell without a window, see: [how to run a PowerShell script without displaying a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window)