# Synchronize two folders on windows with two linux server folders

Tags: linux, powershell, scp, winscp

I have a linux server that has two folders that are periodically filled up. I am using winscp and an extension to keep one folder up to date https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_keep_local_directory_up_to_date

This launches a powershell and only synchronizes one folder. Is there a way to synchronize two folders at the same time and also run in the background (not as a open power shell window).

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "synchronize"? Is it like a folder with text/log files inside, and you need both of them have the same version of latest log files?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that.

Comment: Just run two instances of the script in parallel?

Comment: Also, see [How to run a PowerShell script without displaying a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1802127/850848).