# Flutter: How to increase scroll speed of the mouse wheel on Windows

Tags: windows, flutter, scroll, mousewheel

When I use the mouse wheel to scroll in a ListView on Windows, it is very very slow. If I use the mouse to drag, it works fine.

Is there any way to increase scroll speed of the mouse wheel for Flutter Apps on Windows?

Flutter (3.0.4, on Microsoft Windows)

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_improved_scrolling

Answer (score 0):

You can set your scroll settings in here:

settings/Mouse/Choose how many lines to scroll each time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Flutter functionality, but it's always possible to do the following trick.
You must have access to the Windows file system and administrator rights in order to pass a command to executable exe files that are the starter file to run the code of programming languages designed to execute Windows commands.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe
C:\Windows\System32\vbscript.exe
```

Maybe the following link will be helpful for you to take the first step.

[How to run a PowerShell script without displaying a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window/59345636#59345636)

Maybe it's even a second step, but you'll still have to go through it if you don't want to have Windows executable flashing windows while your program is running or maybe vbscript.exe otherwise.