# How can I view a log file from powershell console ? (i.e. powershell equivalent of 'less')

Tags: windows, powershell, less-unix

What is the powershell equivalent of 'less'?

I see 'more', but it lacks some of the features I rely on (e.g. searching through the file)

I seek a pager (equivalent of 'less') which allows searching (match or ignore case), multiple files at once, etc.

Some of our servers run windows 2008 and I lack admin privileges to install cygwin

I had heard windows 2008, MSFT got their act together and provided some easy-for-admins tools.

Update:

I should give some context:

- I know little about power shell
- New servers have 2008 on them
- While I affection for many tools of yore, the dos prompt is not one of them
- I was hoping that Powershell had the equivalent of grep,ls,less, xargs, et
- I understood that powershell gave us those tools
- I fired off my question quickly.

thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It reads like you know you can do this:

> gc logfile.log | more

(GC is an alias for Get-Content).

You may be able to do the filtering etc.. with this more information can be found by running these commands:

> Get-Help Get-Content  Get-Help
>
> Get-Content -Examples

(Get-Help gc would work fine as well).

And the bits you may be interested in are limit\filter etc...

> Get-Help gc -Parameter * | more

Comment: Do not works with objects, things are not separated by objects

Comment: @MUYBelgium I don't follow your comment, the command is used to read large amount of text. what are you trying to do with an object?

Comment: This does not work for very large (big data) files. gc pulls it alll into memory.

Comment: @garglblarg Actually [`more` was originally an old command from unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command)) that MS ported to DOS (and still exists in unix today). Later, `less` was written for unix, but MS never ported that, unfortunately.

Comment: less is much better than more, for example it allows you to scroll and search through the text

Answer (score 5):

I just use the [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) version of less, works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any direct analogue for less in powershell that you can implement easily. Your best bet is to get a windows implementation of [less that is outside of cygwin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/less.htm), that way you can just drop in the binary somewhere accessible to your account.

Answer (score 2):

to get grep/vim/wget and other Linux like commands in powershell I suggest running.

```
iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring(‘https://get.scoop.sh’)
```

then

```
scoop install grep
scoop install perl
scoop install vim
```

and to get a list of all of them

```
scoop search
```

Comment: another good extension is the powershell community extension set.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about scoop. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10 PowerShell + Cygwin I use:

```
gc .\myfile.log | less
```

Previously I was trying to use cygwin directly:

```
less .\myfile.log
```

but it shows binary file because of invalid charset setting between 32b-bit and 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

> I was hoping that Powershell had the equivalent of grep,ls,less, xargs, et

In the case you missed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573623/powershell-vs-unix-shells) (top voted) you might enjoy this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573623/powershell-vs-unix-shells#answer-573786).