# Equivalent of git verify-pack -v | sort | tail

Tags: git, powershell

In the [Git Book section on Maintenance and Data Recovery](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery), there is a subsection called Removing Objects. Scott writes:

> you can identify the big objects by running another plumbing command
>   called git verify-pack and sorting on the third field in the output,
>   which is file size. You can also pipe it through the tail command
>   because you’re only interested in the last few largest files:

This is the code he suggests:

```
$ git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-29…69.idx \
  | sort -k 3 -n \
  | tail -3
```

How do we run the same command in PowerShell?

- the [bash sort](http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html) command sorts a text file,

  - `k` specifies the sort field,
  - `n` specifies sorting numerically.
- the [bash tail](http://ss64.com/bash/tail.html) command reduces the length of the output.

This is as close as I have been able to come to a solution:

```
(git verify-pack -v .\.git\objects\pack\pack-0e..38.idx)[0 .. 3] | `
    foreach 
    { 
        write-host $_.split(' ')[2] 
    }
```

Here is a sample of what `git verify-pack -v ...` outputs:

```
c2589792c0dd8e400e9ab34bcaeaa03c83628b56 commit 250 167 12
b00b0018214d14b85b79e7221f539635a5796254 commit 245 165 179
b0b582b1a11cc458889e7d4af5a1f91e5648ebae commit 245 164 344
b6487e1c2f6e990cfd8792e6e284a1bc1a1866ba commit 245 161 508
15b676a27a5bac42b54a48d2ce468240b88b58db commit 245 164 669
9db62a7c083f7c2639091ba4c6314618391597d0 commit 250 170 833
1ff58566ef86274f1159149f331dbe0822ab9c5e commit 87 99 1003 1 15b676a27a5bac42b54a48d2ce468240b88b58db
fa384751fcc9a076e9b079eb6626fcbaec1bcec2 commit 225 152 1102
95d914e401ef4ca4104e0adc3d286b2b9d4fa567 commit 226 153 1254
9245007a7e47cd7101c742365b7ddb269d68fe8c commit 224 152 1407
e8e884122a67a637f1c73fc85a74752300208e9c commit 224 152 1559
1aa69b868746c775a886040b60f6361cb3e5d9a4 tag    144 135 1711
0412d6ed9ae629b3f6f3b70801067517fad9da71 commit 250 167 1846
54e0f302b7ee2c8087ad9c0e9f5c7c08be8a568b commit 249 167 2013
999e6b549275fb09f15a796b95ff599da669dc7d commit 248 165 2180
9a13dcb923ba4c26644399465395fb374513c0d1 commit 248 168 2345
15f57ab7dd60936d1566ace99b616240cb5d0e50 commit 275 182 2513
76850bfa0d078cf7510c644b6c2d19b89a041ea1 commit 231 156 2695
1c44a577fcbaa7d2a502b82d3d25c5108fc31abd commit 231 159 2851
f69fec0ad0a55c3341224a6c316c28907cb95e06 commit 235 166 3010
2a10d555d386f2b38a1a3d1ea879af86d43f2793 commit 226 156 3176
363788505e64bd6ee312d4010750f04719b9f430 commit 234 161 3332
56f873570e9a5d522401ef0a8536696e84633f25 commit 233 165 3493
abaf26d3d1433702c1248e27b596402f7dc39365 commit 235 160 3658
438e5c1733e8c2d85f8fa5b9ebd04f7f5a9f3889 commit 339 232 3818
2edf8b09d4a8501b1945b2f11554f3edb6c2cd91 commit 227 157 4050
30fc3760d18e89cf4632e2896b09d8dedeb5b7db commit 258 173 4207
07a9ee1d8e400e7095ee5ddfa319d81ec25e9bce commit 236 163 4380
46ba2c795979429ea21d6be50ef09fa3e1ad176b commit 238 163 4543
6309b484b72819038a24217953cf04ff0d8b4707 commit 278 187 4706
b5ebfba04fb69b31ba5fcbcfa729d6ce21ad5786 commit 246 168 4893
81c13b15fa782dcde7cd0e103cbd30df25d102a4 commit 271 185 5061
842c085c3ce384f2ebcb1f00127433ff849456e4 commit 229 157 5246
b2d7e7d9a39eaf7c1d2ce7ebfd7e95deaddd0368 commit 220 155 5403
94bacc454bbce169664ca48bd5b701de75815fd2 commit 245 169 5558
3f523148622390a07423f5883571a1e364c8598c commit 216 151 5727
221b7d6c96c8cf8ea971d0657a5908c99d69b7df commit 216 147 5878
5e470717bc08c771b179b064724d8630b41e0aa9 commit 232 158 6025
d84463328f181b73ebe54119e522efb730d746a3 commit 225 155 6183
b766630167f786be44e98e575579afd06ed56bf2 commit 225 154 6338
1f2204696b7e21702cdf006a010048bf444839a8 commit 241 164 6492
310295eea190420528d25f327e4dd522b27c56e7 commit 228 156 6656
08df4100100e7f083f2006f762154423ba25dbf4 commit 231 159 6812
95bc1a3d5fee0301961170a86107c2550bad2942 commit 290 195 6971
05a07f12763dd701fc6c6304ea2004f3ae1afad1 commit 226 155 7166
a01f5c441c31097ca9162621e2928d0aa01ad941 commit 227 157 7321
c27a4731b6f2f840d18e4356e857ab40cd1acb7e commit 224 154 7478
20bfe86c581607d17cff52bc5a098d7ddc7233c0 commit 228 162 7632
e185bef8378ee2fefee0d490f632d2d14f65889a commit 265 177 7794
42ce6647781faf6a7440902819dde3754bc1304c commit 240 164 7971
d2021ee5c57471be74404a3adaa948111d3dbec4 commit 229 159 8135
052f835cce40f5aa824f62ca8621823bb428c03c commit 234 162 8294
286c58e499bd7942bad2a79d496ed993d9d0408e commit 232 159 8456
615471a764b51f07f7f91279ddc30aeaaa4103bd commit 226 159 8615
5fe49019f72ee6ea243bdc317f43dc6028327f6e commit 223 155 8774
ac923fe279a440381c805068d5c6300bbf4a7c22 commit 223 153 8929
dcba0e55d8c08a1d07725726b67e995c8026456f commit 228 158 9082
79a71ebee4ae18e479138951eb6f187763f30054 commit 339 233 9240
3b39ffd3d97ca1de9c6762086f170420fdfd6931 commit 339 232 9473
da57dc772777c45f6bb84483370fba1204f37a52 commit 238 164 9705
50fdde91cbdcab61f596523182503a310cc28d90 commit 231 164 9869
9d6c6215ff2e444a51b9f21af4c6c79d31ef39c4 commit 238 161 10033
993f4e2742ae61975bd65482b3875cae401c34bc commit 282 185 10194
4ae223483141e55ef52346902b771f6e2533f4da commit 261 173 10379
eb0e4dca3e3c33b2d4bf8700dd2304ddaa2a23da commit 227 154 10552
fce210e497373b393cc9a922d718cc54715a0384 commit 224 151 10706
beccbfbb3baa7f9b6cbd4336bf3c76142db54d45 commit 234 154 10857
3c5008c516ef98208f26bc161efbc00b218c531a commit 253 168 11011
3123a1bfcee4d1dc54c5af04ab05f4ce1b1cf037 commit 232 155 11179
c7a43a2db17e018347b6865a806ee3f24e1e28e9 commit 230 156 11334
73535bc6f80c1a7ddc938732cb470029e42728eb commit 238 160 11490
b6b2be24de8be2762f49ba0cca8989410691f065 commit 231 155 11650
1731bc5a3e5e9174584f4199334db6b255e58c06 commit 238 167 11805
4240540ce760ab1703ed88b8f44d39cfc3fcf26b commit 236 162 11972
07b57ba533a6d0669da82c3ef9a7d7132a292f34 commit 236 163 12134
bb898240810a0f7bdbb7cb51b0c2078a5e1ee941 commit 232 156 12297
62b3c5276e9c4386d35f83beae935212a71da6ab commit 236 161 12453
c37d6f61dee011ba42b11b4374d5c0d4ebac4b6f commit 244 164 12614
92481aab58111be694a0849a9209ed10d030f39c commit 237 160 12778
4284261a49780ae0eb017707e929e79127577488 commit 240 162 12938
76f6adc17c3e6bcf3cc4a5efac4e7287969adb4d commit 238 160 13100
a60a6855576aadfbc3669009e06ae95a245bd756 commit 239 162 13260
083df846cb2d923a3d422ba778e32a69365ce1a6 commit 236 162 13422
0c02636d798cac68f2ae9c42bc0bd62f396500c7 commit 233 156 13584
974d2aad8a1d058e94704b90dab1bc4196449db7 commit 276 183 13740
9d9df7c939127627ae197197439785613d212f6c commit 233 159 13923
ceb844f7adc72cfc5338b438f9ab19047b468cd0 commit 232 154 14082
7a905a922765e2b7654044905d5da53e17bc2388 commit 236 157 14236
4ebf9955f78a1ed5b344ef30c9fbd5bd046a2b71 commit 233 156 14393
e155a23c6aabd8aac164c81b06647006e75cc0f9 commit 188 126 14549
8a88774a1ef98f8617a53a344c852a60d7e3b767 tree   616 493 14675
2551c3ef8c8c655728774b218e1e425b6fdcb4d1 tree   11 22 15168 1 8a88774a1ef98f8617a53a344c852a60d7e3b767
701e6a5e80798954d28200aad21d6ff1eaf3d075 tree   40 51 15190
b9e6c51b0066be48f8ad933ab26193a3122644ea tree   276 253 15241
613c380a82bed15414b4f6384e4b7ccb48f3c054 tree   155 152 15494
b941bb02a367434f3e3c02d31921215fb6992c58 tree   114 118 15646
eb75a1c7543b558893fe0b3d03debe6955e194d8 tree   114 119 15764
3f5006b28dce46bd500b7f791f89c2245db56f76 tree   77 85 15883
975461e05f96482a811a7eacfccfdf90899eaa19 tree   40 51 15968
cd0e31dd2bd9cf4e1416e14acd87fdb14fd27345 tree   40 51 16019
2dda70ee0728ab0560531182adc6003a13ba3270 tree   40 50 16070
8864c0baa3a5c4f4b56cc218a9eb80ae9566f01b tree   40 50 16120
b2c1e753782f45ad415399f3f5087a4134281213 tree   40 51 16170
1b9804338fe2867371b2b88ad07721c2079bbb07 tree   40 51 16221
54ec1cee60a0f9b3147d0fbc6e31bba8452ceb6e commit 86 98 16272 1 0412d6ed9ae629b3f6f3b70801067517fad9da71
f349be957ee9cc5704bfd8ab183e086120c129ef commit 104 111 16370 1 0412d6ed9ae629b3f6f3b70801067517fad9da71
0ac31794762e72102c5093ef7031075494d24149 commit 80 92 16481 1 a01f5c441c31097ca9162621e2928d0aa01ad941
8338bc67ff114d3e06a701b7f32d503f0d6a871e commit 112 113 16573 1 79a71ebee4ae18e479138951eb6f187763f30054
d3230bac921d43d7f3a748cd407a0f651c2c0990 commit 96 108 16686 1 3b39ffd3d97ca1de9c6762086f170420fdfd6931
8e243569ef169c3cee4f6979161682b9911179c0 blob   67 72 16794
1a87cac2d630b9edbe3f00234135bbca742777b1 blob   4 14 16866 1 8e243569ef169c3cee4f6979161682b9911179c0
127d53f36cf358f0e4a07559465643b3aed38c73 blob   220 171 16880
ecbae1f80c413b295d03cc2c2c83a5759803f335 blob   6 17 17051 1 127d53f36cf358f0e4a07559465643b3aed38c73
d123ac65cc8122a6ca3b8d33367efb7b0c219eea blob   5 16 17068 1 127d53f36cf358f0e4a07559465643b3aed38c73
adf1acb6be5d7120f2a32595caf65e233c20b09b blob   4772 1925 17084
bde2795db6e42a2ddba37b002627b18086e94cba blob   114 122 19009 1 adf1acb6be5d7120f2a32595caf65e233c20b09b
7ad1398abfffaa83ce2c1b4e413c18c197f1b484 blob   10 21 19131 1 adf1acb6be5d7120f2a32595caf65e233c20b09b
5118b4921ce44210bf3b55549a958db33de84f01 blob   18 30 19152 1 adf1acb6be5d7120f2a32595caf65e233c20b09b
c8d8c7858bbf48e26f662322b1c54c1296c2de83 blob   221 161 19182 1 adf1acb6be5d7120f2a32595caf65e233c20b09b
2fb2f8102c0676260928c7c9874a343918709a0d blob   12 23 19343 2 7ad1398abfffaa83ce2c1b4e413c18c197f1b484
7831b2b81def34d1893495111a7da52326854e2b blob   12 23 19366 2 7ad1398abfffaa83ce2c1b4e413c18c197f1b484
02721dbe370c9b820babcf5b01c76325284df6f1 blob   132 143 19389 2 7ad1398abfffaa83ce2c1b4e413c18c197f1b484
5748eca630cd0113541a7ba73f0620ecad3a8837 blob   11 22 19532 3 02721dbe370c9b820babcf5b01c76325284df6f1
4378100273ab35ec256db17ca8715d905f6d6330 blob   26 39 19554 3 02721dbe370c9b820babcf5b01c76325284df6f1
da03d7c4dda1a73361f4ebeb7061001195f60e9f blob   16 27 19593 4 4378100273ab35ec256db17ca8715d905f6d6330
ef3c41b542046232de3802e38f583c4ae00c056b blob   20 32 19620 4 4378100273ab35ec256db17ca8715d905f6d6330
8d01cc6e3c1ed6b35235981cb3f7aa4bc6bb0c11 blob   84 94 19652 5 ef3c41b542046232de3802e38f583c4ae00c056b
ff9968cc695d223a0b456e80674528836c7578b6 blob   21 33 19746 6 8d01cc6e3c1ed6b35235981cb3f7aa4bc6bb0c11
165f327f5753560c0f1e16e02b25683cad55c7f8 blob   136 134 19779 6 8d01cc6e3c1ed6b35235981cb3f7aa4bc6bb0c11
2f1b62d6d2d8000fd9d746b81ce8ae02c762da17 blob   282 177 19913 7 165f327f5753560c0f1e16e02b25683cad55c7f8
320f82fe8cdcd24dab8ed36954925e7ca5ab6fdf blob   16 29 20090 7 165f327f5753560c0f1e16e02b25683cad55c7f8
e291b74eaa231169a38b6fbda0c6860116948389 blob   21 34 20119 7 165f327f5753560c0f1e16e02b25683cad55c7f8
e17ec2f234d00a12235faf02505c40416d12c88e blob   98 76 20153 7 165f327f5753560c0f1e16e02b25683cad55c7f8
983315dd9387c5743a32c90047914060f3dd89e2 blob   12 22 20229 8 e17ec2f234d00a12235faf02505c40416d12c88e
937244f564afff26b05d07b73eb9c57c11b10338 blob   25 37 20251 8 e17ec2f234d00a12235faf02505c40416d12c88e
d5d6ebe831ca650ad4994f81aedb7f81d75b2135 blob   21 34 20288 8 e17ec2f234d00a12235faf02505c40416d12c88e
45b89cc29fea4868b09c154a3ab8b1fa6d6e5266 blob   84 97 20322 8 e17ec2f234d00a12235faf02505c40416d12c88e
8b8da7a086c4318f2f8d324ee058101285265798 blob   217 174 20419 8 e17ec2f234d00a12235faf02505c40416d12c88e
8e41aa114734031501491f78b66396ff53cb0883 blob   85 94 20593 9 45b89cc29fea4868b09c154a3ab8b1fa6d6e5266
4a685007f0715fd33a3faebe719c04f693d80e7f blob   28 40 20687 10 8e41aa114734031501491f78b66396ff53cb0883
5855515cbc3b96809eeaaf2e195d3454b4499abd blob   23 36 20727 10 8e41aa114734031501491f78b66396ff53cb0883
233b2462fd787d3435a1f7851faedaf57a03da40 blob   32 40 20763 9 8b8da7a086c4318f2f8d324ee058101285265798
7beca6a749b870c3b0e144c9c2ef2ea56f65f99a blob   166 137 20803 10 233b2462fd787d3435a1f7851faedaf57a03da40
663e9167225fc3e460524869c31d5e2022ef74de blob   120 108 20940 10 233b2462fd787d3435a1f7851faedaf57a03da40
3c14f1ffbbf4cd0f6562b6dd2554b7cb34f85d16 blob   30 41 21048 11 663e9167225fc3e460524869c31d5e2022ef74de
9880db1c334ab526d5e684192a6e1b5dca5f4aa7 blob   18 30 21089 2 c8d8c7858bbf48e26f662322b1c54c1296c2de83
ce2d30e200e6806ffdefb21d6eb9d1b55ee0a662 blob   22 35 21119 2 c8d8c7858bbf48e26f662322b1c54c1296c2de83
c4c59520ba6efaa32f7c2e640846ad8991eb66fe blob   24 35 21154 3 ce2d30e200e6806ffdefb21d6eb9d1b55ee0a662
ec8a53acb065cff249aeb20d171ba8ec8272f5b5 blob   78 87 21189 3 ce2d30e200e6806ffdefb21d6eb9d1b55ee0a662
a92df4d43614cf24137ebcb6217b37d2eb60b27b blob   42 55 21276 3 ce2d30e200e6806ffdefb21d6eb9d1b55ee0a662
5fec4ba68cd3ac4d79e27ef345105294f22f4924 blob   12 22 21331 4 a92df4d43614cf24137ebcb6217b37d2eb60b27b
06b076bf9ac80ec7beca53cb6411ff7da3dc4eb0 blob   141 127 21353 4 a92df4d43614cf24137ebcb6217b37d2eb60b27b
e773f7244f8053cae28edd2515c67c2494b48ab1 blob   7 18 21480 5 5fec4ba68cd3ac4d79e27ef345105294f22f4924
13546aeea614de9d6cfdfccb062aa9359ae73668 blob   40 52 21498 5 06b076bf9ac80ec7beca53cb6411ff7da3dc4eb0
d3d18e866b1b56fe8ef8f0dc2f6083b7525a5e6e blob   5057 1849 21550
1c0c8351735fa21a02c8ea49d3d9127152e86a76 blob   523 380 23399 1 d3d18e866b1b56fe8ef8f0dc2f6083b7525a5e6e
92c6e3a1bb199d395d00083c6d1a41c1c51fd236 blob   12 23 23779 1 d3d18e866b1b56fe8ef8f0dc2f6083b7525a5e6e
f8641be42c06df3a71600ea504f99a12948797c7 blob   103 86 23802 2 92c6e3a1bb199d395d00083c6d1a41c1c51fd236
ed20ff46cd27b6d30efc8a1b314a7dc0b0eeb003 blob   80 86 23888 2 92c6e3a1bb199d395d00083c6d1a41c1c51fd236
9c6eb06197281d90d32f95ed0a2849105a95e48a blob   189 149 23974
3b99f2a0e5a8db6d7d1675673e84fdfc17b6dec5 blob   6 17 24123 1 9c6eb06197281d90d32f95ed0a2849105a95e48a
c2bb32d43385840a7f78974830173f6f336490ab blob   6 17 24140 1 9c6eb06197281d90d32f95ed0a2849105a95e48a
8f061179b8f47f62543df561f96ecfb730968135 blob   6 17 24157 1 9c6eb06197281d90d32f95ed0a2849105a95e48a
f667a925cc9def4c77ce4f6f2658a65713777fe7 blob   6 16 24174 2 8f061179b8f47f62543df561f96ecfb730968135
824431bb8149992c86ee91aa6525480af3a09efc blob   23 34 24190 3 f667a925cc9def4c77ce4f6f2658a65713777fe7
cc13cdbef434743f99fb7ef3461137f722296c4f blob   9 19 24224 3 f667a925cc9def4c77ce4f6f2658a65713777fe7
96cbd44e782c975abc9602f63d7197e92c9dc459 blob   4 14 24243 4 824431bb8149992c86ee91aa6525480af3a09efc
2fb676fac1b1eb2ccbad7df221bac6f4c249ddb9 blob   4 14 24257 4 824431bb8149992c86ee91aa6525480af3a09efc
7e202d912179fde863ad8c7c52a9bf9fab5b2254 blob   4 14 24271 4 824431bb8149992c86ee91aa6525480af3a09efc
f8faf22b1c672b54ed7e904935d1f2338ed91038 blob   1084 315 24285
3609f20ebd357679b111783e8afaf36ec46427f3 blob   4 13 24600
1d6ed9fa3e56a172f8a0c3df58b3625f7c0593ea blob   14 23 24613
c52c2adb4d7c741cd74af08745a5318d96ee73ac blob   1326 385 24636
f8ec32c5ae08ba9a8c14f0fd90550444e071fc87 blob   61 50 25021 1 c52c2adb4d7c741cd74af08745a5318d96ee73ac
fc4172501b782d97990c3c55098b8c437df076dd blob   56 47 25071 2 f8ec32c5ae08ba9a8c14f0fd90550444e071fc87
2cc0dd2440ae49817d7542b995baadff82ea8974 blob   4405594 4405845 25118
0996c46feb9b06dcb1ccff06b93c7e749e2e668b blob   18 28 4430963
cc7a9daf5657360d5453d876a557037dabdd1787 blob   166 98 4430991
d9fd604b901e8a4efde1424cf017c2bb1e6e7ba6 blob   71 75 4431089
345e6aef713208c8d50cdea23b85e6ad831f0449 blob   5 14 4431164
467838fa5d7e817652a77d5d0a555e60b2477b1b tree   32 49 4431178 1 8a88774a1ef98f8617a53a344c852a60d7e3b767
644e0e3d33eb7464a8451caaefe7b8a01b69c3eb tree   15 26 4431227 2 467838fa5d7e817652a77d5d0a555e60b2477b1b
46661e20bceb3df987e11674616cefd5ba237165 tree   11 21 4431253 2 467838fa5d7e817652a77d5d0a555e60b2477b1b
c3fcf4dac258c1f71348d8ab8bbc571d19bf5d43 tree   11 21 4431274 3 46661e20bceb3df987e11674616cefd5ba237165
c9eeedc8fd6e356a08f39d54c277c4992616a4b8 tree   34 48 4431295 3 46661e20bceb3df987e11674616cefd5ba237165
28019ba0fb73b72ddc701b0224a3aee6e8edb1cc tree   34 46 4431343 3 46661e20bceb3df987e11674616cefd5ba237165
1a48d7d61101bf2031597c5fd02c8d1d474289ea tree   34 49 4431389 3 46661e20bceb3df987e11674616cefd5ba237165
4244007833713f7d0d999533a86f6848c96940db tree   31 43 4431438 4 1a48d7d61101bf2031597c5fd02c8d1d474289ea
16293eb1b72dcd910b35015fa22c86f8ba027197 tree   55 69 4431481 4 1a48d7d61101bf2031597c5fd02c8d1d474289ea
28318fdba0552895a3ccde6edc9adf5fbd327a1e tree   32 44 4431550 5 16293eb1b72dcd910b35015fa22c86f8ba027197
e4e3dfb6c05d5e10a76ea90cd7cafb784c803fba tree   32 46 4431594 5 16293eb1b72dcd910b35015fa22c86f8ba027197
1ef94bd4a960adb47b39a7d8d6285b3591704cb0 tree   10 21 4431640 5 16293eb1b72dcd910b35015fa22c86f8ba027197
5b6ec8819904511a47cdcc3bcceccff94e146a7d tree   34 49 4431661 5 16293eb1b72dcd910b35015fa22c86f8ba027197
b10253fada0b89e25f4925550ea5cac4d6e81108 tree   70 84 4431710 6 5b6ec8819904511a47cdcc3bcceccff94e146a7d
cf8a86ec198290656f15579248942a33904ce24f tree   31 44 4431794 6 5b6ec8819904511a47cdcc3bcceccff94e146a7d
8b7463676437a199bb80f6283608ccb01cd0e1e8 tree   31 44 4431838 6 5b6ec8819904511a47cdcc3bcceccff94e146a7d
72d15d20819cdc10ef8dc58f107cf1a8318eedf9 tree   31 44 4431882 6 5b6ec8819904511a47cdcc3bcceccff94e146a7d
4ef6b82168ae5020658e530a57ec5b74ad5cc7ab tree   70 85 4431926 6 5b6ec8819904511a47cdcc3bcceccff94e146a7d
ee3a3ecf517d284c5a90cc88ff52e986ae4ed8fc tree   30 45 4432011 7 b10253fada0b89e25f4925550ea5cac4d6e81108
adefc1b5b93dee6a8822f31d62a0c29962ba0431 tree   32 44 4432056 8 ee3a3ecf517d284c5a90cc88ff52e986ae4ed8fc
1c21718e63dd793a30303ee537e08aa822611823 tree   55 69 4432100 8 ee3a3ecf517d284c5a90cc88ff52e986ae4ed8fc
c2b126e09e5434fde6757e2f2ae49763d1061915 tree   11 22 4432169 8 ee3a3ecf517d284c5a90cc88ff52e986ae4ed8fc
3c3148125e9e7622a142d5e2f1b6bffd8d0d15cc tree   34 47 4432191 8 ee3a3ecf517d284c5a90cc88ff52e986ae4ed8fc
f9ac6d9020d237bfd9925ed2ba44a929c7bc2ffc tree   11 22 4432238 9 1c21718e63dd793a30303ee537e08aa822611823
20206bb3611759181f6627147924746fd021b347 tree   34 47 4432260 9 1c21718e63dd793a30303ee537e08aa822611823
1939d11278c19cd51b2bbbc5832884200997e821 tree   59 74 4432307 9 1c21718e63dd793a30303ee537e08aa822611823
b4fff15943ed15e2dc3b13577c2e27d9b714ee1c tree   34 47 4432381 9 1c21718e63dd793a30303ee537e08aa822611823
81e2ef5e310184f530dae1508b11597beca80bfe tree   34 47 4432428 9 1c21718e63dd793a30303ee537e08aa822611823
ff1a4a1e9da2cc93f34eab1b21eb64db64369bcc tree   34 47 4432475 9 1c21718e63dd793a30303ee537e08aa822611823
72217fab2e19b72754964d928fdaf7170b5830b6 tree   34 47 4432522 9 1c21718e63dd793a30303ee537e08aa822611823
1a934863912029e38c636476486b06b079468d03 tree   34 49 4432569 9 1c21718e63dd793a30303ee537e08aa822611823
eba52f18b1bd462501d186e01e6130f084bac558 tree   34 47 4432618 9 1c21718e63dd793a30303ee537e08aa822611823
fc5b5ff657cccfb81062f31a51260b4633135e4d tree   34 47 4432665 9 1c21718e63dd793a30303ee537e08aa822611823
e0c11dd87b103fc8d8688e7eca5aa1af11f10cb9 tree   34 47 4432712 9 1c21718e63dd793a30303ee537e08aa822611823
ef034495441e75e4fe5c015b183932a5b0efa147 tree   31 43 4432759 10 e0c11dd87b103fc8d8688e7eca5aa1af11f10cb9
2ea685c88c694b58b5bc31a3fa4d42ba5205caa0 tree   55 69 4432802 10 e0c11dd87b103fc8d8688e7eca5aa1af11f10cb9
5c74ecca0d1c960a7e2deaf12b61c02e0107078b tree   55 70 4432871 10 e0c11dd87b103fc8d8688e7eca5aa1af11f10cb9
398813e6b2298ee6fa6f4dd17c48b788ba36f61b tree   55 70 4432941 10 e0c11dd87b103fc8d8688e7eca5aa1af11f10cb9
bd3bed8ef665bf7eaa0ea85a41429a4ea16603a6 tree   54 68 4433011 11 398813e6b2298ee6fa6f4dd17c48b788ba36f61b
47dfdee196d0cc6557c761c0e0374973f2ff0d23 tree   30 42 4433079 12 bd3bed8ef665bf7eaa0ea85a41429a4ea16603a6
b5f5546f8063812e507b4802e822f34c34ac69c2 tree   30 42 4433121 12 bd3bed8ef665bf7eaa0ea85a41429a4ea16603a6
19d6bbae17428385ebc3865932f3238c42832a5c tree   54 69 4433163 12 bd3bed8ef665bf7eaa0ea85a41429a4ea16603a6
bd9e3c444dd00ff8f0f745a6fb770d58d2c95093 tree   30 42 4433232 13 b5f5546f8063812e507b4802e822f34c34ac69c2
59a2a3b591d4f436599ea3aada517eac446ef73b tree   9 20 4433274 13 b5f5546f8063812e507b4802e822f34c34ac69c2
78951388edec611f367d94a691646bc991c095f7 tree   10 21 4433294 13 b5f5546f8063812e507b4802e822f34c34ac69c2
4fcefbf2acb2ee5e43b9759d2db2df467ff235cb blob   14 23 4433315
0104208f7c468c62a536d4eef420dfd69eda43fb blob   8 17 4433338
e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 blob   0 9 4433355
e965047ad7c57865823c7d992b1d046ea66edf78 blob   6 15 4433364
f479ae17fc53a929d9311d64de50f02739481193 blob   14 23 4433379
c755205dd92f46952e3e409d1be8e2108b7b6d1f blob   8 17 4433402
cba0bc04f48072f66b96e4b2f986e85baab7f77f tree   30 47 4433419 1 b9e6c51b0066be48f8ad933ab26193a3122644ea
a2f4d08ee603196a5284109a5387df19d0011a48 tree   30 45 4433466 1 b9e6c51b0066be48f8ad933ab26193a3122644ea
e9b501656dfc3a974c757a882fc796b50f1bbc14 tree   30 45 4433511 1 b9e6c51b0066be48f8ad933ab26193a3122644ea
a8f6a8a48f2fdb9b59d3b1ce01959cb4daa533a0 tree   30 45 4433556 1 b9e6c51b0066be48f8ad933ab26193a3122644ea
e376b7b3208edaba7ae59633ab8e20e8df3bd9e5 tree   70 87 4433601 1 b9e6c51b0066be48f8ad933ab26193a3122644ea
8634f25150e38b127b1b966feb9181f644647119 tree   70 87 4433688 1 b9e6c51b0066be48f8ad933ab26193a3122644ea
1f7c45b227d6d33e0fbab1c0b7e9ee637512803c tree   70 87 4433775 1 b9e6c51b0066be48f8ad933ab26193a3122644ea
5beeb8b3e93bd5603fa4df80eaec5a89a6820dbb tree   70 87 4433862 1 b9e6c51b0066be48f8ad933ab26193a3122644ea
fa85d74c119b245572baf189dcda0c126f7dafc4 tree   70 87 4433949 1 b9e6c51b0066be48f8ad933ab26193a3122644ea
cda7b0332b6ee018fcd4ef5a6cbf5a87e9664238 tree   70 87 4434036 1 b9e6c51b0066be48f8ad933ab26193a3122644ea
1ea8c9632f4ff7c1836e49aebceb42da54740544 tree   6 17 4434123 2 a2f4d08ee603196a5284109a5387df19d0011a48
d71e405b7c266837452fb2f3201a054d7cdfba2b tree   30 43 4434140 2 a2f4d08ee603196a5284109a5387df19d0011a48
a8ca5a421ec8766b2348279271664f1bd14266ad tree   30 43 4434183 2 a2f4d08ee603196a5284109a5387df19d0011a48
66c088350c9fddb26f1db8db06c56d80d3fb51a2 tree   30 43 4434226 2 a2f4d08ee603196a5284109a5387df19d0011a48
02fa3061cb595930c555824c33b8130493b4c367 tree   30 45 4434269 2 e9b501656dfc3a974c757a882fc796b50f1bbc14
8d2dc52f42ef8f5ab6cc4d6f09a514cfdc60f758 tree   30 43 4434314 2 e9b501656dfc3a974c757a882fc796b50f1bbc14
17f88cf2611bf4102f4a7f177da03e2e292d57f9 tree   30 43 4434357 2 e9b501656dfc3a974c757a882fc796b50f1bbc14
29cb8d08844076d15799a70549b629454ce5f52b tree   49 62 4434400 2 cda7b0332b6ee018fcd4ef5a6cbf5a87e9664238
36464dcf42d0ecbd9d8bc0124af50e0f28346b83 tree   30 42 4434462 3 29cb8d08844076d15799a70549b629454ce5f52b
d3007c552e51cc21bb917c37ce0c120b92e2e6aa tree   30 42 4434504 4 36464dcf42d0ecbd9d8bc0124af50e0f28346b83
37a763a521b045cfec6b4aed65e5812849f30125 tree   30 44 4434546 4 36464dcf42d0ecbd9d8bc0124af50e0f28346b83
9565d357d0820132e4188dff6c3b73a4099346d8 tree   30 43 4434590 4 36464dcf42d0ecbd9d8bc0124af50e0f28346b83
01a574a9a9eb506c5da47c18e06bb5ea971e0472 tree   9 19 4434633 5 9565d357d0820132e4188dff6c3b73a4099346d8
36fbe17f1ce6ffe717978a88cf301cd2baf5345d tree   33 47 4434652 5 9565d357d0820132e4188dff6c3b73a4099346d8
989285dfc1cfa37d731e6efc796c7ef4c31cb475 tree   33 47 4434699 5 9565d357d0820132e4188dff6c3b73a4099346d8
e497902eaf011bc449f889748c930555f5e06de2 tree   33 46 4434746 5 9565d357d0820132e4188dff6c3b73a4099346d8
03c9f445ced64ecde621ea6d978610954ace1b76 tree   27 39 4434792 6 e497902eaf011bc449f889748c930555f5e06de2
91a43623dc2c5b510fb3756a12d4a346fc28b34d tree   30 42 4434831 7 03c9f445ced64ecde621ea6d978610954ace1b76
233d3299a430dde9c0410f582882650390e7452e blob   51 58 4434873
3682553ecde543f5d49a988710c7faf35ec582ed blob   44 51 4434931
9a18288d15b5ddfc95c91d3177792ae1cb5946f7 blob   42 49 4434982
37cd342e081937cbc0d01e3a6a53904388c16b5d blob   34 42 4435031
07c95028b3b9dcad150eb6e2693a8e34be5413a6 blob   20 28 4435073
ce9654b9f396328ec31b3acc7b25e794ee5a34ae blob   18 28 4435101
ba38391cdb9a4c5bf166ec009187dd775586a003 tree   6 19 4435129 1 613c380a82bed15414b4f6384e4b7ccb48f3c054
f1d9f7c7ad5e7f6bfa5b4cd7525fe16453432923 blob   59 65 4435148
3f7e3f029c4b05069f587a840976d87c06f8607f blob   56 63 4435213
9f4f02ab525a19ea768713a918f68daa047c2448 blob   29 39 4435276
4541bfe061cce7c18aadbc0114238b853bacaeaf blob   18 28 4435315
non delta: 132 objects
chain length = 1: 32 objects
chain length = 2: 19 objects
chain length = 3: 12 objects
chain length = 4: 12 objects
chain length = 5: 11 objects
chain length = 6: 8 objects
chain length = 7: 6 objects
chain length = 8: 9 objects
chain length = 9: 13 objects
chain length = 10: 8 objects
chain length = 11: 2 objects
chain length = 12: 3 objects
chain length = 13: 3 objects
.\.git\objects\pack\pack-0e7a477ced94d85adae445baeec72e2651d5e438.pack: ok
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the `git verify-pack -v` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-29…69.idx | Sort {[int]($_ -split ' ')[3]} | 
    Select -Last 3
```

If the `-k` value is 1-based, change the array index above to 2 as PowerShell array indices are 0-based.

Comment: Adding `| where { $_ -notlike "*:*" }` avoids casting errors on summary lines.

Comment: Good point. I didn't scroll down far enough in your sample output to see the summary lines.

Comment: I made further changes and posted my own answers. It's verbose!

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell usually works on [objects, not strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/573861/1630171) like Unix shells, so you'd convert the string output to objects (for instance with [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849890.aspx)), and then filter the object list via [`sort`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849912.aspx) and [`select`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx).

```
$idx     = '.git/objects/pack/pack-29…69.idx'
$headers = 'SHA1', 'type', 'size', 'size-in-packfile', 'offset-in-packfile',
           'depth', 'base-SHA1'

(git verify-pack -v $idx) -match '^[a-f0-9]{40} ' -replace ' +', ',' |
  ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $header |
  ForEach-Object { $_.size = [int]$_.size; $_ } |
  sort size |
  select -Last 3
```

The `-match` operation removes those lines that don't start with an SHA1 hash, and the `-replace` operation collapses adjacent spaces into a single delimiter, so that `ConvertFrom-Csv` won't create empty fields when there is more than 1 space in a row.

The `ForEach-Object` loop in the pipeline converts the `size` field from string to integer, to allow numeric sorting in the next step.

The header list was taken from the [`git-verify-pack`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-verify-pack.html) man page.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Keith Hill's excellent guidance, this is what actually worked:

```
# put the verify-pack results into a variable
$idx = ".\.git\objects\pack\pack-e3aa4ad72d76e52dc538d6d8c9e3de95b523957f.idx"
$vp = git verify-pack -v $idx

# remove the summary values at the end (that have a colon in their string)
$vp = $vp | where { $_ -notlike "*:*" }

# convert to 2x tab separated values for consistency and readability
# because it was space separated with inconsistent spacing
$vp = $vp -replace "\s{1,}", "`t`t" 

# sort and select
$vp = $vp | sort { [int]($_ -split "`t`t")[2] }
$vp | select -Last 3

# result
# --------------------------------

adf1acb6be5d7120f2a32595caf65e233c20b09b        blob        4772        1925        19219
d3d18e866b1b56fe8ef8f0dc2f6083b7525a5e6e        blob        5057        1849        23685
2cc0dd2440ae49817d7542b995baadff82ea8974        blob        4405594     4405845     27253
```

Whew. That was verbose compared to bash.

Answer (score 0):

With a custom PowerShell function, this can be done with the following command:

```
get verify-pack -v $idx | delim | 
> where { $_[1] -match 'blob' } | 
> sort { [int]$_[2] } | 
> select -l 20
```

`delim` is an alias for the `ConvertTo-DelimitedString` function, which produces objects that produce the entire original string when `ToString()` is invoked and allow index access to the delimited segments.

You can add the following code to your PowerShell profile script to gain this function:

```
Add-Type @"
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class DelimitedString
{
    private readonly string original;
    private readonly string[] segments;

    public DelimitedString(string original, string[] segments)
    {
        this.original = original;
        this.segments = segments;
    }

    public string this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return segments[index];
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return original;
    }
}
"@

Function ConvertTo-DelimitedString
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $True)]
        [String]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [String]
        $Delimiter = "\s+"
    )
    Process
    {
        New-Object DelimitedString -ArgumentList $_, ($_ -split $Delimiter)
    }
}

New-Alias -Name delim -Value ConvertTo-DelimitedString
```

Now if Microsoft would include this kind of functionality in PowerShell, allow `Where-Object` and `Sort-Object` and kin to specify indices for property names, and add a `-Numeric` switch to `Sort-Object`, we would be all set!