# git verify-pack and PowerShell

Tags: git, powershell

I am trying to port this script to PowerShell:

https://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/git-script-to-show-largest-pack-objects-and-trim-your-waist-line/

In PowerShell I run [git verify-pack](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-verify-pack) from the root of my repository with:

```
git verify-pack -v .git\objects\pack\pack-*.idx
```

But I get the error:

```
fatal: Cannot open existing pack file 'C:\test\MyRepo\.git\objects\pack\*.idx'
C:\test\MyRepo\.git\objects\pack\*.pack: bad
```

I took a look at:

[Equivalent of git verify-pack -v | sort | tail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741662/equivalent-of-git-verify-pack-v-sort-tail)

but it does not really address the wildcard `pack-*.idx`. Is that not possible in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Git relies on wildcard expansion by shell. In PS you have to do it yourself:

```
git verify-pack -v (Get-ChildItem '.\.git\objects\pack\*.idx')
```