# Migrate from Unix to powershell, vs Cygwin on windows

Tags: linux, bash, powershell

I am a standard linux user; I spent years learning how to use that nice tool called shell scripting.

I do most of my daily work in the shell, which include editing files, copying them, move them, rename them and of course, find and process content of files.

Now I moved on Windows 10 as environment; to use linux I run it in a VM.

Although I am at the point where either I learn powershell, or I install Cygwin, so I can continue to use Windows but with a familiar shell command environment.

I am not sure if it is worth to learn powershell, since I do not work with it...it would be just for the sake of using it on windows for the occasional time, when I need to move a ton of files or do operations that (should)take less time in a shell than doing it via GUI.
On the other side, there is Cygwin, never used it but I was told that it is exactly like having a linux terminal with bash on it, and that you can access the whole system, not like I do in the VM, just the virtual OS area.

I am not asking which is better, I am leveraging on your expertise, to know which would fit more my needs and case.

EDIT -------------------------

Not sure why this is on hold; as usual, some people see a question as "opinion based", when the description state clearly that the question has nothing to do with "preferences", but with measurable and logical statements.

80% of the questions related to the choice of a tool or language are based on logic evaluations about the operation to perform; only not-knowledgeable users would suggest a tool based on preference, because that would display a total lack of understanding of the problem. Even the choice of a text editor can boil down to a specific logic argument, not just "use whatever you like".

Hope this clarify the question.

Comment: You can't just download Cygwin to see if it will work for your needs, and make your decision based on that?

Comment: yes, that would be a very logic approach; although I may not spend enough time in Cygwin, to see if there are fundamental differences. Who use it already, can tell me in few words which solution would befit more my case. I thought was faster to get a straight answer, instead than try both of them and see.

Comment: My point was that you're already experienced in the shell, so a quick install of Cygwin would tell you if it supports the things you need to do. You could do that test; if Cygwin supports the things you need to do, then use it. If not, then you need to learn Powershell. We don't know what you're going to need to do.

Comment: I see; it make sense. I will go ahead and try Cygwin first then. Most of my workflow on windows is to change file names in batch, move them or rename them following certain criteria. There are tools for GUI that does the same; but I prefer the text way...it is illogic I know.

Comment: ICYMI: Microsoft will bring a Linux subsystem including bash to Windows: http://techcrunch.com/2016/03/30/be-very-afraid-hell-has-frozen-over-bash-is-coming-to-windows-10/

Comment: To complement @L3viathan's helpful link with another: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopersCanRunBashShellAndUsermodeUbuntuLinuxBinariesOnWindows10.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its worth learning Powershell because:

- There are indications that it will be available on Linux
- Bash over Cygwin simply doesn't feel like native tool. There are too many quirks that one must account. Its far better for you to use Ubuntu on Windows with its native bash shell if you want to use bash.
- SSH is coming as native service on Windows so you will be able to use Powershell within windows machines from Linux environment.

Working with both almost every day I think that Powrshell is by several orders of magnitude better shell then anything Linux has to offer and you should at least give it a chance. For some reasons see for example [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/47ueie/fulltime_linux_admin_amazed_and_suprised_by/d0ftmqu) reddit comment (or entire thread). People that work on Powershell have strong Unix background so you will find the shell has familiar concepts and names for Linux administrator.

Answer (score 2):

I did find this question, which is somehow answering part of mine.

[Is PowerShell ready to replace my Cygwin shell on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573623/is-powershell-ready-to-replace-my-cygwin-shell-on-windows?rq=1)

It is not a duplicate, but it mention differences between Cygwin and Powershell, so at least it will be useful tfor an informed decision.