# Powershell, escaping specific character in string variable not present in regex escape method

Tags: powershell, rest, escaping

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527772/how-to-ignore-escape-sequences-stored-in-powershell-string-variable) I learned that I can use [Regex]::Escape() to escape all [the commonly escaped characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-5.0) in string variables. The problem is that I'm going to use a path that contains & characters and then use that in a URL for a RestAPI call, and that escape method does not escape the & character.

When the path contains & the API interprets this as an operator in the URL and is not parsed correctly:

```
$MyPath = "\\Server\Share\Something & Something Else"
$MyURL= "http://localhost/Address/to/APIResource/"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri ("$MyURL" + "?path=$MyPath") -UseDefaultCredentials
```

The ?path=$MyPath is the problem, since $MyPath contains & and will therefore not work. How can I escape the & character inside $MyPath to make it work with the RestAPI?

Comment: for URI/URL items, i think you should use ... Uri.EscapeUriString(String) Method (System) | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapeuristring?view=net-5.0

Comment: I'll take a look at this first thing in the morning and see if it works, thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome! good luck ... [*grin*]

Comment: I tried this one, it seems that it strips the string of the characters rather than escape them? The answer posted by Mathias seems to just modify the URL to have character encodings instead of spaces and the actual characters so I will try that. As in, [URI]::EscapeDataString("\\Server\Share\Something & Something") becomes %5C%5CServer%5CShare%5CSomething%20%26%20Something so that does look correct.

EDIT: Correction, I must have done something wrong, your suggestion does give me a result, but does not change the & so that is still interpreted as a command in RestAPI.

Comment: it looks like `Mathias R. Jessen` got the right version for you. glad to see that his solution worked as you need ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I learned that I can use `[Regex]::Escape()` to escape all the commonly escaped characters in string variables

And now you'll learn that that isn't true at all :)

`[regex]::Escape()` *only* escapes characters that would otherwise risk being interpreted as escape sequences *as defined by .NET's regular expression grammar* - it's designed for, and only guaranteed to work in, that context.

---

For URI parameters, you'll want to use [`[uri]::EscapeDataString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapedatastring):

```bsh
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ("$MyURL" + [uri]::EscapeDataString("?path=$MyPath")) ...
```

Comment: Nice one. Very helpful.

Comment: This very much looks like it does what I'm looking for! Will verify in live environment and get back to you if it worked but just trying [URI]::EscapeDataString("\\Server\Share\Something & Something") gives me %5C%5CServer%5CShare%5CSomething%20%26%20Something as a result so very promising!